# mysql remove all middle-initial at the end of name

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with data like this.

```
Fullname
Adarna, Neil D.
David, Jundemil P.
Greg, Dart .
```

I want to remove middle-intials at the end of fullname

so the data looks like this.

```
Adarna, Neil
David, Jundemil
Greg, Dart
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

Its give only string before second space all string after 2nd space will remove

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('column_name', ' ', 2);

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Adarna, Neil D.', ' ', 2);
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('David, Jundemil P.', ' ', 2);
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Greg, Dart .', ' ', 2);
```

Hopefully this will work for your case

Comment: its not possible i tried in my computer `SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Jundemil P. Greg', ' ', 1),' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX('Jundemil P. Greg', ' ', -1)) ` and out put is `Jundemil Greg`

Comment: you can also try in your computer, run it

Comment: my format is something like this   Greg, Jundemil P.

Comment: Adarna, Neil D. this is whole name ?

Comment: in your example my format is this Greg, Jundemil P.

Comment: All i want is to remove all last string... eq.. "P."

Comment: means you want to remove last string like  D. , P. , . ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100938/discussion-between-vipin-jain-and-freddy).